# Failed to pull from git automatically

Tags: git, bash

I have a startup script that is supposed to sync the git repo on the machine with master

```
git pull -r origin master
```

Getting

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    file1.py
    Folder2/file3.rb
    Please move or remove them before you can merge.
    Aborting.
```

tried solving this using

```
git clean -df
git clean -dn

git stash
git checkout master
git pull -r origin master
# to pull new branches
git fetch
```

still getting the error. 
How can I ensure successful pull from master?

[This is done automatically.]

Thanks

Comment: I guess you want to merge `master` in your current branch. Because if you just want to have the contents from master you can remove the repo and clone it again (expensive) or just `git fetch origin && git reset --hard origin/master` (cheaper)

Comment: Thanks @CarlosCampderrós . it worked. write it as an answer and i'll approve

Comment: I have created an answer with a slightly longer explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to have the contents from `origin/master` in your local copy discarding any local change you have 2 options:

- you can remove the repo and clone it again. This is an expensive operation (it depends on the repo size), but it guarantees you that no other files other than the ones in the remote repo are present in your local copy.
- or you can update your local copy discarding all changes to tracked files by running `git fetch origin && git reset --hard origin/master`. This is faster than the full clone option because it will only have to fetch the new commits in the remote repo that you don't have locally. This has the small problem that your working copy can potentially have more files that you have in the remote repo. Doing `git clean -dffx` will remove everything not tracked by git, so you'll end up with a clean copy of the remote repo.

Answer (score 1):

> error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:

If you have no important local changes then do `hard reset` your `local/master` with `remote/master`.

```
$ git fetch
$ git reset --hard origin/master
```

**N.B:** Potentially `hard reset` dangerous command, since it throws away all your uncommitted changes and local commits that have not in `remote/master`.

---

**Alternative:**

Add the untracked files.

```
$ git add .
```

Go back to a clean working directory by `stashing`. Keep your local modifications away and `reverts` the working directory to match the `HEAD commit`.

```
$ git stash
```

Now pull origin master.

```
$ git pull origin master
```

Comment: hi sajib, `git add .` didn't work. end up using `git fetch origin && git reset --hard origin/master`

Comment: Ok. `hard reset` is another solution (may be dangerous a little bit) also. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have added these two files to the repository,

```
file1.py
Folder2/file3.rb
```

And didn't commit. So if you don't want these files manually delete these files from your repository & your script will work fine after that

**Update**

If you want a generic way,

- To remove directories, run `git clean -f -d` or `git clean -fd`
- To remove ignored files, run `git clean -f -X` or `git clean -fX`
- To remove ignored and non-ignored files, run `git clean -f -x` or `git clean -fx`

Comment: Thanks DilumN, I'm looking for a more generic solution. One that would force the git software to pull from master either way. I'm aware of the manual solution.

Comment: Updated the answer